# Is it possible to read and write the same file when iterating lines?

Tags: python

I am trying to enforce that a file is tabulated in python and I would like to read and write the file at the same time, perhaps it's not possible because the pointer has already moved away when trying to write.

Consider the `file.txt`

```
chr1 557044 557064 FUS 1000 +
chr1 870106 870128 FUS 1000 +
chr1 936672 936706 FUS 1000 +
chr1 1433046 1433067 FUS 1000 +
```

I am running the following code to make this file tab delimited:

```
with open(file="file.txt",mode='r+') as file:
    for line in file:
        file.write('\t'.join(line.strip().split() + '\n'))
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Comment: Incorrect bracket placement. `file.write('\t'.join(line.strip().split()) + '\n')`

Comment: The bigger problem is that `file.write(...)` will overwrite whatever bytes (not necessary exactly one line) the iterator would have read next. You rarely want to read and write access to the same file, especially a text file. Instead, write to a temporary file and replace the original when you have successfully created the new one.

Comment: @not_speshal if I create a lot of empty space between my words and try to run again the script the file is kept unchanged. P.S: I did correctly placed the brackets this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the errors because you are trying to add a list and a string together.
`.split()` will create a list, and adding a `'\n'` to that list is the reason why it errored out

Answer (score 1):

To deal with extra spaces between words, `strip()` each word in the line before you `join()` with tabs. As an aside, collect all the text you want to write into a variable (`contents` in the below code) and write it after the required formatting.

Try this:

```
contents = ""
with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        contents += "\t".join(word.strip() for word in line.split()) + "\n"

with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting error because split return a list and you are trying to add str with list you can get you task done by:

```py
with open(file="file.txt",mode='r+') as file:
    file.write(file.read().replace(" ", "\t"))
```